# Converting Json array into list of strings in C# 4.5

Tags: c#, json

I have a json file as following:

```
"Steps":[
{"divisor":"13","dividend":"47","product":"39","quotient":"3","remainder":"8"},

{"divisor":"8","dividend":"13","product":"8","quotient":"1","remainder":"5"},

{"divisor":"5","dividend":"8","product":"5","quotient":"1","remainder":"3"},

{"divisor":"3","dividend":"5","product":"3","quotient":"1","remainder":"2"},

{"divisor":"2","dividend":"3","product":"2","quotient":"1","remainder":"1"},

{"divisor":"1","dividend":"2","product":"2","quotient":"2","remainder":"0"}

]
```

I want to read this in C# and convert it to list of array. Please help.

Comment: `list of array` ??? array or list???

Comment: It should be `list` of `objects`

Comment: Wouldn't you want to convert it into a `List<Operation>` or something similar, where `Operation` has properties of `Divisor`, `Dividend` etc? (It seems odd that all those values are in strings, mind you...)

Answer (score 4):

It is very easy, use [json.net](https://json.codeplex.com/)

```
public void GetJson()
{
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("filename.json"))
    {
        string data = r.ReadToEnd();
        List<Step> steps = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Step>>(data);
    }
}

public class Step
{
    public int divisor { get; set; }
    public int dividend { get; set; }
    public int product { get; set; }
    public int quotient { get; set; }
    public int remainder { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is a list of objects. `{}` are objects in JSON, and `[]` are arrays. There are no "lists" in JSON.
This is how it should be deserialized using Json.NET library:

```
public class Step
{
    public int divisor { get; set; }
    public int dividend { get; set; }
    public int product { get; set; }
    public int quotient { get; set; }
    public int remainder { get; set; }
}

public class StepsResponse
{
    public Step[] Steps { get; set; } // It can be a List<Step>
}

// ... 

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StepsResponse>(jsonString);
```

By the way, your JSON is invalid. It should be arounded by curly braces like

```
{
    "Items": ...
}
```